# Wikidata statement ordering

Tags: sparql, wikidata, blazegraph, wikibase

I am using the RDF dump format of Wikidata, according to Wiki this format does not have the ordering of statements. I want to have attributes always in order, such as this "inception" is always followed by "official names", https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q60

Where can I get this ordering information?

When I used blazegraph, the ordering is always so random when queried with SPARQL. It never fixed.

Comment: You can use SPARQL and `order by` anything you want. Otherwise, it simply returns results in a non-specified order (modulo some implementation things indeed) Clearly, you have to define this ordering. By the way, are you sure that the statements are ordered by anything? If so, by which measure are they ordered?

Comment: AFAIK, properties on pages are ordered in accordance with this list: https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/MediaWiki:Wikibase-SortedProperties. See also https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T125493 and subtasks. Perhaps it is possible in SPARQL to figure out some ordering for particular classes using `VALUES (?property ?order) {(wd:P580 15) (wd:582 16)}` etc.

Comment: @aksw hi, I am aware of that "order by" clause, but I need the existing ordering data that is already defined, there are thousands of properties, I can't simply define manually the position for each. I think it's my code that cause random order. Thanks

Comment: @StanislavKralin Thanks, that's the information that I am looking for. Although it's unfortunate that the position/order is not predefined in the rdf data itself to makes the job easier.

Comment: HTH: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Wikibase_Client/Lua#mw.wikibase.orderProperties

Comment: @StanislavKralin That's nice, thanks so much.

Comment: @Willia, that sounds like the sort of feature that could be requested on the bug tracker @ http://phabricator.wikimedia.org tagging #wikidata

Answer (score 0):

The default order on a repo comes from the MediaWiki:Wikibase-SortedProperties page of the repo.

So for wikidata.org that is https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/MediaWiki:Wikibase-SortedProperties

Client sites can be configured differently but for all Wikimedia clients this currently points to the same page.

There is currently no more structured way to access this data, other than just getting the wikitext, so no access in SPARQL, but that is the sort of feature that could likely be requested.