# Wikidata SPARQL property values order

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I found that Wikidata API returns the data with some relevance order. For example look at the `occupation`values of https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q22686 and compare with `occupation` values list from here:

```
  VALUES (?company) {(wd:Q22686)}
  ?company ?p ?statement .
  ?statement ?ps ?ps_ .
  ?wd wikibase:claim ?p.
  ?wd wikibase:statementProperty ?ps.
   ?statement wikibase:rank ?rank.
  OPTIONAL {
    ?statement ?pq ?pq_ .
    ?wdpq wikibase:qualifier ?pq .
  }
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en" }
}
```

[Try it](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3FwdLabel%20%3Fwd%20%3Fps_Label%20%3Fps_%20%3FwdpqLabel%20%3Fpq_Label%20%3Frank%20%7B%0A%20%20VALUES%20%28%3Fcompany%29%20%7B%28wd%3AQ22686%29%7D%0A%20%20%3Fcompany%20%3Fp%20%3Fstatement%20.%0A%20%20%3Fstatement%20%3Fps%20%3Fps_%20.%0A%20%20%3Fwd%20wikibase%3Aclaim%20%3Fp.%0A%20%20%3Fwd%20wikibase%3AstatementProperty%20%3Fps.%0A%20%20%20%3Fstatement%20wikibase%3Arank%20%3Frank.%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fstatement%20%3Fpq%20%3Fpq_%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%3Fwdpq%20wikibase%3Aqualifier%20%3Fpq%20.%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22%20%7D%0A%7D)

Is there a way to preserve property values order for SPARQL query?

Comment: which order exactly do you want? I mean, on the web page it's more or less randomly, isn't it?

Comment: @UninformedUser web page order looks more relevant for me

Comment: @UninformedUser The first place isn't politician what actually true for current period of time.  Please have a look at https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q6279 - politician is the first.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49704919/wikidata-statement-ordering#comment86424123_49704919

Comment: @StanislavKralin isn't the question more about the ordering of the values of a particular property like `occupation`?

Comment: @UninformedUser exactly